# Rearranging column order in ArcGIS Pro table frame

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, table-frame

I have created a table frame in ArcGIS Pro and want the columns to appear in the order that they do in the attribute table (VCI - Drought severity - area (km2) - % of total area). However, they will only appear in the order as shown in the image. How I can I rearrange the column order?

[image: table frame]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way seems to be to drag the rows into the desired order within the relevant part of the table of contents

[image: Screenshot]